# need many parameters on construction c++03

Tags: c++, builder, c++03

I have an object that looks somewhat like

```
class Block{
     Type1 member1;
     Type2 member2;
     Type3 member3;
     ...
     //many many MANY members (hundreds, if not thousands)
}
```

I need to create a convenient way to construct Block.

This calls for the builder pattern, but as shown here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern
it seems I would exceed the maximum number of parameters allowed on the constructor.

How should I do this?
Separation to smaller blocks is an option i would rather avoid.

Thanks

Comment: **Why** do you want to avoid to create smaller blocks ?

Comment: You should want to group members that are closely related to each other.

Comment: I want to avoid smaller blocks because the bigger block is some old code I have no intention of getting into. More-so, the "members" are global variables, unorganized, ungrouped, and barely named.

Answer (score 0):

There should be design issue here, I don't think you really used the hundreds members. class should be designed the simple the better.
You should provide more details for this class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are groking the builder pattern. Define a configuration object. Define individual methods to set the configuration object. Then use the configuration object to instantiate object.

```
class BlockCfg {
    //...
    void setMember1 (Type1 val);
    void setMember2 (Type2 val);
    //...
};

class Block {
    Block (const BlockCfg &cfg);
};
```

Comment: what if I need my Block to be configured STATICALLY?

Comment: Define a way to statically create `BlockCfg`.

Comment: That brings us back to the same parameter problem, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. If you only need static initialization, then you should not use the builder design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You could make `BlockBuilder` a `friend` of `Block`, then have the `BlockBuilder` functions directly modify the member data rather than passing in all the data to the constructor. The downside of this is that all the members of `Block` will be default-constructed, which might be fine if most of the types are built-in, but might be expensive.

However, having hundreds of members in a class is a massive code smell and you should think about a redesign.